# Java MongoDB queries, inserting 2 '$or' conditions

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to generate a MongoDB query with Java like the following:

```
{
   "$or": [
      {
         "user": {
            "$exists": true
         }
      },
      {
         "parent": {
            "$exists":true
         }
      }
   ],
   "working": 1,
   "$or": [
      {
         "car.id": 3846,
         "car.mediaType": 1
      },
      {
         "car.matched.id": 3846,
         "car.matched.model": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

But I cannot do it because when the second `$or` condition is being added, the first one is overwritten.

I need to search with some of the results of each `$or`, I can't add it in the same `$or`. The code is:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBList;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;

public class Sample {
    public function mongoSearch()
    {
        BasicDBObjectBuilder queryBuidlerType = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("working", 1);

        BasicDBObject user = new BasicDBObject("user", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));

        BasicDBObject parent = new BasicDBObject("parent", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));

        BasicDBObject car = new BasicDBObject();
        parentMatch.put("car.id", mId);
        parentMatch.put("car.model", mModel);

        BasicDBObject carMatched = new BasicDBObject();
        parentMatch.put("car.matched.id", mId);
        parentMatch.put("car.matched.model", mModel);

        BasicDBList or1 = new BasicDBList();
        or.add(user);
        or.add(parent);

        BasicDBList or2 = new BasicDBList();
        or.add(car);
        or.add(carMatched);

        queryBuidlerType.add("$or", or1).add("$or", or2);

        DBObject queryType = queryBuidlerType.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need at least one case of each $or to occur it seems to me that you need an and condition. And (FirstOr, SecondOr), i haven't worked with mongodb in java for a while so i might be wrong here

Comment: @RafaelSaraiva : actually you're right

Comment: I am just happy i could help. Keep up the good work. Actually there is already an answer and all. cool

Comment: I'll try with AND condition, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$and` wrapping both `$or` :

```
{
   "$and": [
    {"$or": [
          {
         "user": {
            "$exists": true
         }
          },
          {
         "parent": {
            "$exists":true
         }
          }
       ]},
       {"$or": [
          {
         "car.id": 3846,
         "car.mediaType": 1
          },
          {
         "car.matched.id": 3846,
         "car.matched.model": 1
          }
      ]}
    ],
   "working": 1
}
```

And also, I don't know what you're trying to do, but if you want to match "car.id": 3846" AND "car.mediaType": 1 in the same sub-object, consider using `$elemMatch

In Java :

```
QueryBuilder queryBuidlerType = QueryBuilder.start("working").is(1);

DBObject or1 = QueryBuilder.start().or(QueryBuilder.start("user").exists(true).get(), QueryBuilder.start("parent").exists(true).get()).get();
DBObject or2 = QueryBuilder.start().or(QueryBuilder.start("car.id").is(mId).and("car.model").is("mModel").get(), QueryBuilder.start("car.matched.id").is(mId).and("car.matched.model").is("mModel").get()).get();

queryBuidlerType.and(or1, or2);

DBObject queryType = queryBuidlerType.get();
```

Comment: Well, the Json sample is not the real one and it doesn't care very much. The important thing is the `$and` answer that I thought it but I haven't tried it. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I gave you in example in Java, also.